# Identifying/exporting adjacent polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, adjacency

I have many polygons (US Counties) with agricultural land data in them. I would like to identify and export (ideally into excel) the data from the counties that are adjacent to the ones with agricultural land use data.

Is there a way to do this quickly or en masse in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2?

Answer (score 3):

An approach is:

1. select the polygons with your agricultural data (e.g counties where wheat is only grown). You would do that with your select by attribute tool.
2. Then run the select by location tool and choose the spatial selection method as share boundary.
3. Finally you would run the table to Excel tool to export your attribute.

If you need to do this many times, explore using model builder to automate it all into a single tool.

Comment: I'll give that a go Hornby and let you know, thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer